# Помощь в решение ошибки «Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in X on line Y»

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток!

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку такого рода:

> **Warning:**  file_get_contents(/papka/file.dat) failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>
> **Warning:**  file_put_contents(/papka/file.dat) failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Теоретически понимаю, что `php` не может найти `/papka/file.dat`, хотя `file.dat` как раз и не было, думал "ручками" создать, и ошибка исчезнет, но нет, ошибка как висела, так и висит. Права на папку `/papka/ 777` а файл `dat 644`. В чем может быть причина? Даже `dirname (__FILE__)` не помогает.

Comment: Трудно сказать без конкретного примера, видимо все-таки где-то кроется ошибка. Однако, рассматривать нужно на конкретном примере, на искусственном выглядит совершенно необъяснимым глюком.

Comment: Если в file_get_contents(); указать полный путь сайта с http:// то ошибка изсчезает, но в данном случае file_get_contents, однако на put_contens() нельзя http:// указывать. :/

Comment: Да, он качает по сети, поэтому file_get_contents() может извлечь файл, запросив его у сервера. Когда вы обращаетесь к файлу, вы указываете абсолютный или относительный путь?

Comment: Указываю абсолютный путь, включая с http://...

Answer (score 1):

Ограничения могут быть:

- на уровне конфигурации PHP (например, open_basedir).
- На уровне конфигурации веб-сервера
- На уровне окружения (chroot, права на папки и т.д.)

Чаще всего проблема банальна и заключается в некорректных путях: используется относительный путь в одном месте и абсолютный в другом.